# Can oven cleaning sprays poison the quality of the food baked in an oven if not cleared away?

Tags: oven, cleaning

I want to ask Is it good to use oven cleaning sprays to clean oven. Does the quality of the food baked in an oven will not goes down or become unhealthy?

Comment: It's going to depend heavily on what's in them. Many are based on a strong alkaline solution. Are they the ones you're thinking of? As far as I'm aware, all state they should be rinsed well, and you don't normally put food on the oven's surfaces directly - or do you?

Comment: I once sprayed window clean in my oven instead of water when baking focaccia, pretty horrible experience as you can imagine. The bread tasted and smelled of window cleaner and I threw it away. I imagine oven cleaner being left on the oven's interior surface would be similar, if not worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe

**If you use it properly and follow the instructions**.

When I clean my oven with those products, I make certain it is well wiped cleaned with clean water after and I will let the oven run empty for a little to make certain that if there's some left over product, it will be evaporated.